# mysql resets authentication plugin settings to default

Tags: mysql, authentication

I'm using mysql 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

By default it has auth_socket for mysql.plugin settings and I changed it to mysql_native_password. But sometimes it resets to default auth_socket settings and I don't understand the reason, what causes this changes?
I didn't update mysql before the issue.

Comment: — Did you ever properly resolve this? I keep having this problem pop up on servers that I manage and as of right now I just log in and manually change the `plugin` field whenever it happens :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should give a try to [`--default-authentication-plugin`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-authentication-plugin) option.

[People in comments here](https://askubuntu.com/a/801950) (despite the question is different with yours) report about same magic happening next to mysql packages (auto)updating process; so the problem origin seems to be in update script(s) which overwrites `mysql.user.plugin` with internal default value.

P.S. keep in mind that the correct way to set up privileges is via issuing `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'somepass';`. This is better than using "low-level" `UPDATE mysql.User ... SET plugin = ...; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`, but I'm sure you are already familiar with both approaches.

Comment: — Do you have any more info on what update scripts do this? I'd very much like to be able to override this behavior as this resetting of the plugin field keeps happening on multiple servers that I manage.

Comment: `apt-get source mysql-server`; Take a look at `debian/mysql-server-5.7.postinst` inside unpacked directory: I believe that something in there is trying too hard to do it's work.

Comment: It also happened to me on Ubuntu 18.04. On automatic upgrade of mysql, if you set empty password for root user, the plugin will revert back to `auth_socket`. To prevent this, either set a password for root user or disable the automatic update of apt. The latter is not recommeded for security reason though.